# getRunningAppProcesses() returns only my app

Tags: java, android

I use this method to get all running app processes in background

```
        list = new ArrayList<AppProcessInfo>();
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
            AppProcessInfo abAppProcessInfo = null;

            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcessList = activityManager
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();
      //      publishProgress(0, appProcessList.size());

            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo : appProcessList) {
         //       publishProgress(++mAppCount, appProcessList.size());
                abAppProcessInfo = new AppProcessInfo(
                        appProcessInfo.processName, appProcessInfo.pid,
                        appProcessInfo.uid);
                try {
                    appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(appProcessInfo.processName, 0);
    ...........................
.............................
```

but when i run my application in my device ( android 6.0 ) i get only my app process can anyone help to modify this function to work 
i see this https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses
but i don't know how to use it because i use the different structure in my function?

Comment: Please only post code that is relevant to the question, otherwise people are going to put as much effort into helping you as you put into asking the question.

Comment: I request help to adapt this library in the question that you post with my code because i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this library 
https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses/
and i update my code to this

```
list = new ArrayList<AppProcessInfo>();
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
        AppProcessInfo abAppProcessInfo = null;

        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcessList = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
  //      publishProgress(0, appProcessList.size());
        List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (AndroidAppProcess appProcessInfo : processes) {

            String processName = appProcessInfo.name;

            Stat stat = null;
            try {
                stat = appProcessInfo.stat();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            abAppProcessInfo = new AppProcessInfo(
                    appProcessInfo.name, stat.getPid(),
                    appProcessInfo.uid);
            try {
                appInfo = appProcessInfo.getPackageInfo(mContext, 0).applicationInfo;
.........................
```

it's working now 
thank you

Comment: Google has significantly restricted access to `/proc` in Android Nougat. This library will not work on Android 7.0.